# Does one "wince in pain" or "wince with pain"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

I have seen both in common use and I want to know which is more preferable.

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it! Can you provide an example sentence? As a side note, you can consider "writhe in pain", if you aren't too confident about "wince".

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Does one "writhe in pain" or "writhe with pain"? ;-)

Comment: @kyle - It depends on how you want to use it! Can you provide an example sentence? :P

Answer (score 1):

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wince_INF%20in%20pain%2Cwince_INF%20with%20pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cwince_INF%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwinced%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwincing%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwince%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwinces%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cwince_INF%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwinced%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwince%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwincing%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwinces%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0#t3%3B%2Cwince_INF%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bwinced%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwincing%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwince%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwinces%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cwince_INF%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bwinced%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwince%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwincing%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwinces%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0) says *wince in pain* is more popular of late.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Either one](http://ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/wince). Although, to be honest, "wince **with** pain" sounds better to me.

Answer (score 0):

As an editor, I prefer **"wince in pain,"** but this is just my opinion. I do not believe there is a definitive answer to your question, just expressions of individual preference.

Comment: You mean, "primarily opinion-based?" ;)

Comment: Exactly, BiscuitBoy. :-))